# DialogFragment - Where to access layout components [i.e. editText.setText("")]

Tags: android, android-layout, nullpointerexception, android-dialogfragment

after doing a lot of research and trying (i think) every lifecycle method i could find, i´m really stuck:

**What i want:** Basically i have this DialogFragment ("ProfileUsernameDialogFragment")which should present my layout file ("fragment_profile_header_username_dialog").
in this layout file i have some TextViews and some EditTexts. I want to set the text of these EditTexts to some value i obtain in my programm, so setting it beforehand is not possible.

**What i have:**

```
public class ProfileUsernameDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

...

@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    EditText usernameText = (EditText) this.getView().findViewById(R.id.username_field);
    usernameText.setText("TEST");
}

@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Log.d(AppController.LOG_STRING, this.getClass().toString() + " - onCreateDialog  - START");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this.getActivity());
    View view = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_header_username_dialog, null);
    builder.setView(view);
    builder.setPositiveButton(SAVE_SETTINGS, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            // Tried this too:
            // EditText usernameText = (EditText)
            // ProfileUsernameDialogFragment.this.getView().findViewById(R.id.forename_label);
            // usernameText.setText("TEST");
        }
    });
    builder.setNegativeButton(ABORT_ACTION, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    });
    builder.setTitle(CHANGE_NAME_SETTINGS);
    Dialog dialog = builder.create();
    return dialog;
}
}
```

**What i get:** is a NullPointerException, no matter which position for the findViewById(R.id.username_field) i tried. 
(I also tried onCreate and some other methods, i start thinking i might have another problem than the code location, but i really hav no clue) I tried to follow at least 6 similar questions about NullPointers in DialogFragments so i guess i need advanced help ^^

i should add i´m completely new to android so please be nice, but convention tipps etc. are very welcome! thx in advance :)

Comment: what do you mean with "setting it beforehand"

Comment: view.findViewById(R.id...) should work

Comment: i meant that i cant use a string resource or something like that. i am not sure what you mean with should work? what i have at the moment doesnt work - what should i change or do you have any idea what other problem i could have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following is what you need:

```
mAlertDialog.setOnShowListener(new DialogInterface.OnShowListener() {

        @Override
        public void onShow(final DialogInterface dialog) {

            final Button b = mAlertDialog.getButton(DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
            b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(final View view) {

                    v.findViewById(R.id...)
                }
            });
        }
    });
            });
        }
    });
```

Comment: thank you very much! i tried to access the view always by getView() which did not work, your answer worked for me. so for others: one has to use the view which was created here :  `View view = this.getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.fragment_profile_header_username_dialog, null);`

Answer (score 1):

Another option in addition to @David's answer is to use the onStart() method.

It looks like you were thinking along these lines in your question, except you used the onActivityCreated() method.

So for example:

```
    @Override
    public void onStart() 
    {
        super.onStart();
        EditText usernameText = (EditText) this.getDialog().findViewById(R.id.username_field);
        usernameText.setText("TEST");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Android documentation has good [example](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#Showing%20a%20Dialog%20Fullscreen%20or%20as%20an%20Embedded%20Fragment.)

So, if You wont set text in Your layout You need set it in `onCreateView()` method, for example:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup cont,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout to use as dialog or embedded fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.app_info, cont, false);
    TextView title = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_header);
    TextView content = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_content);
    Button button = (Button)view.findViewById(R.id.dialog_button);

    title.setText(this.dialogTitle);
    content.setText(this.dialogContent);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view){
            getDialog().dismiss();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
```